# How to allow user to create/delete/ all privileges to any database that starts with a prefix (PG 15)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

For example,

User potato can only create and delete databases that starts with abc_ .

The purpose is to allow a CI process to create/delete prefixed databases on a shared postgresql cluster. So I want to limit the permission of this user to only be able to manage db's with a given prefix.